# WebGL support - which browsers?

Tags: browser, html, html5

Which browsers (and which versions) support WebGL?

In particular I am interested in checking [Three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/), but I do not want to limit this question about a particular WebGL framework or a page.

Comment: If this search is related to your previous question , it makes sense to mention your Android version too

Comment: I do not think it is related, but I may be wrong. I think there is an indirect relation - some Web browser versions require some Android version, however I hope the Web browser version directly tells about WebGL version. If I am wrong in this respect, it will be good if an answer can provide the additional info.

Comment: I am not sure, was trying to help in achieving your goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General information

The website [Mobile HTML](http://mobilehtml5.org/) seems to contain some information. It lists WebGL as supported by following platforms + browsers:

- Android 4+ and Chrome 30+, with following comment:

> On Chrome 27-29 available enabling an experimental flag. On Chrome 30 it's enabled but on most devices you need to enable the flag 'Override software rendering list'

- Opera Mobile 12+
- Firefox (no version information)

There is no information about how complete the support is, the website claims:

> HTML5 compatibility on mobile and tablet browsers with testing on real devices

Other page where one can check support for HTML5 features is [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=webgl), which lists following for Android Browsers:

- Opera Mini: not supported
- Chrome 55: partial support
- Firefox 50: partial support
- Android Browser- Android 5-6.x WebView Chromium 53: partial support
- Opera for Android 37: supported

### Chrome support

As for Chrome, the WebGL was probably enabled by default in some later version. I am now testing on a Xoom with Chrome 49 and I can run even WebGL specific three.js demos like [geometry / convex](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_convex). When going to `chrome://flags`, the WebGL option described does not exist, there are only flags for enable draft and 2.0 experimental extensions. When going to `chrome://gpu`, I can see *WebGL: Hardware accelerated*.

### Testing results on Motorola Xoom + Chrome 49

The support is really "partial", some three.js WebGL examples work ([geometry / convex](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_convex)), some don't ([geometry colors](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors)), some work, but run very slow (like 1 FPS in [camera / logarithmicdepthbuffer](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer)).

When checking `chrome://gpu`, I can see many error messages logged starting with *Shader translator allowed/produced an invalid shader unless the driver is buggy*.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser supports WebGL but it is disabled by default. Here's how you can enable it:

**1.**  Type **chrome://flags** in the address bar.

**2.**  Tap Enable under "Enable WebGL" on the flags menu.

**3.**  Tap the Relaunch button.

**4.**  Navigate to http://get.webgl.org to verify that you have WebGL support. You might get a message saying that the support is experimental.

Source: http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-enable-webgl-support-on-chrome-for-android